# Why tag '.' doesn't work in NSRegularExpression

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsstring, numeric, nsregularexpression

I have this string :

```
NSString* yourString = @"(;GM[1]FF[4]SZ[19]AP[CGoban Pro:2.2]PW[Michael Redmond]WR[9p]DT[2010-12-12]KM[6.5]RE[B+0.5]AN[Michael Redmond]BK[1]C[toto : [test]]";
```

And i have this regular expression :

```
NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression
                              regularExpressionWithPattern:@"((RU)|(KM)|(TM)|(OT)|(PW)|(PB)|(WR)|(BR)|(WR)|(DT)|(RE))\\[[\\w ]+\\]"
                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                              error:&error];
```

I can't have the numeric value with \w and \. or only . return nothing !
Can anybody could help me ?

thanks

Comment: What are you expecting as a result, and what are you actually getting? Also, it would be helpful if you showed how you were making use of the regular expression object.

Comment: Works for me. I get matches "PW[Michael Redmond]" and "WR[9p]". Are you also trying to capture "KM[6.5]" or "DT[2010-12-12]"?

Comment: yes.
i have regular text with \\w but i don't have 6.5 or 2010-12-12.
How can i get all of them ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `\\[[-+. \\w]+\\]`. That will match letters, numbers, space, plus, minus, and period. Note that `-` has to be first because `-` in the middle indicates a range like `[a-z]`.

Alternatively, if you just want to match anything inside square brackets and don't care what it actually is, try `\\[[^]]+\\]`. That will match `[`, then anything that is not `]`, then `]`.